# WPF - GridView items inside the listview cannot be properly aligned

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

I have the following .xaml file. That is I have a grid view inside a listview.
gridview contains 2 columns. The issue is that items of the first column cannot be aligned in the way I want it to be.

```
      <ListView ....>
          <GridView....>
              <GridViewColumn Header=" ...." ....>
                 <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel .....>
                                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" ..../>

                                </StackPanel>

                         </DataTemplate>

                 </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
           </GridViewColumn>

         <GridViewColumn Header="....."  ....>
               <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                                 <ItemsControl ItemSource="{Binding NameList}">
                                         <ItemsControl.DataTemplate>

                                                <StackPanel ....>

                                                              <TextBox Text="{Binding ItemName}">

                                                </StackPanel>
                                         </ItemsControl.DataTemplate>


                                </ItemsControl>
                         </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
           </GridViewColumn>
     </GridView>
 </ListView>
```

what I get as the ouput is something like the following.

```
               * Item 1
               * Item 2
 Header 1      * Item 3
               * Item 4
               * Item 5

               * Item 1
  Header 2     * Item 2
               * Item 3
```

what I need is something like the following

```
       Header 1    * Item 1
                   * Item 2
                   * Item 3
                   * Item 4
                   * Item 5

     Header 2      * Item 1
                   * Item 2
                   * Item 3
```

Could someone pls help me to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

found the solution !

```
  <ListView ...>
       <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                 <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
             </Style>
      </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
     .........
 </ListView>
```